# Starting a TF session (and nothing else) uses over 350MB of GPU memory

Tags: tensorflow

The code below

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    while True:
        print("Session is open!")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Uses `363MiB / 16280MiB` according to `nvidia-smi`.

Am I missing something or is this normal? Shouldn't GPU usage be `0MiB` at this point?

Answer (score 1):

It's allocated by CUDA runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to only allocate that once? I am loading three models at the same time (on the same GPU) to do inference in parallel and it seems like a waste to load the runtime three times.

Comment: It allocates this amount only once and only om one GPU if your system has multiple GPUs. And AFAIK, it could only be released by some lower lever tricks, like using `numba cuda`